# how to convert promise pattern to observable pattern using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, visual-studio-code

I have a very long code (in many files) that have promise pattern and I want to convert the pattern to observable pattern.

I do it in vscode by find and replace.

So I create a regex to match the many variations (like \n and space).
All the promise code is the same pattern.

From Promise pattern:

```
   this.service.foo().then(
     function(res) {
         ....
     },
     function(err) {
       ...
     }
    );
```

To observable pattern:

```
   this.service.foo()
    .pipe(catchError(err => { 
      ...
      return err; 
    }))
    .subscribe(res => { ... });
```

How to convert promise pattern to observable pattern using regex? My problem with regex is I don't know how to match two "placeholders" and convert it to new syntax.

Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pattern:

```
(?s)then\(\s+function\(res\)\s*\{\s+(.+)\},\s*function\(err\)\s*\{\s*(.+)\}\s*\);
```

In this pattern I used:

- `(?s)` flag, which enables `.` to match newline characters
- assumptions, that parameters inside lambdas will be named `res` and `err`
- capturing groups `(...)` to capture body of the lambdas

Finally I used replacement pattern:

```
\npipe\(catchError\(err => \{\n\2\nreturn err;\n\}\)\)\n\.subscripe\(res => \{\n\1\n\}\);
```

[Regex101 demo.](https://regex101.com/r/EE2QxT/1)

Example done with Notepad++:

```
this.service.foo().then(
     function(res) {
         var s = res;
         console.log("result of a promise is " + s);
     },
     function(err) {
         cnosole.error("Something went wrong, error: " + err);
     }
    );
```

Output:

```
this.service.foo().
pipe(catchError(err => {
cnosole.error("Something went wrong, error: " + err);
     
return err;
}))
.subscripe(res => {
var s = res;
         console.log("result of a promise is " + s);
     
});
```

Still, you need to take care of formatting.

**EDIT** - VS code adjustments

VS Code doesn't recognize flags, so we need to remove `(?s)` at the beginning, which allows `.` to match new line, with that chagne, we need to change `.` with `[\s\S]`, this patterns match "whitespace or not whitespace", so everything :)

Also, VS Code doesn't match `\s` against `\n`, that's why I replaced `\s` with `[\s\n]`.

Also, capturing groups are referred with `$` sign in replacement pattern.

After correction:

Pattern:

```
then\([\n\s]+function\(res\)\s*\{[\n\s]+([\s\S]+)\},[\n\s]*function\(err\)\s*\{[\n\s]*([\s\S]+)\}[\n\s]*\);
```

Replace pattern:

```
\npipe(catchError(err => {\n$2\nreturn err;\n}))\n.subscripe(res => {\n$1\n\});
```

Comment: in regex101, the flavor you set is PHP. I think this why its not working in vscode, I need it to be in js please. is it something possible to do in js?

Answer (score 1):

In VSC you can't specify flags in the regex (yet). To simulate the `s` flag you have to use `[\s\S]` instead of `.`. And the groups are referenced with `$n` in the replace string.

Search:

```
then\(\n\s+function\(res\)\s*\{\n([\s\S]+?)\},\s*function\(err\)\s*\{\n([\s\S]+)\}\s*\);
```

Replace:

```
\npipe\(catchError\(err => \{\n$2\nreturn err;\n\}\)\)\n\.subscribe\(res => \{\n$1\n\}\);
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/RYckx7/2) example

The problem is you can't count `{` and `}` in regex so if you have any block statement (like `if`) in your `err` function the regex might match but the replace result will be wrong.